# Django:URL Mapping ,Page not found (404)

Tags: django, web-applications, django-views, django-templates, http-status-code-404

I am a newbie to Django. Trying to create my first webapp.

I ran into a problem. I have 3 templates store, kart and checkout. I am able to navigate from store to kart without any issues. Now I wish to move to checkout page from the kart page. I am using a button for this purpose.

Below given is the code present in my kart.html page.
[image]

I am facing the below issue:
[image]

Below  given is my urls.py file

[image]

And this is my views.py file

[image]

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo you are missing %

```
 href="{% url 'checkout' %}"
```